# Special characters in Password are converting URL into a String

Tags: c#-3.0

Special characters in Password are converting URL into a String and truncating the URL after the password in the URL .

Here is what I am using

```
webbrowser.navigate("http://username:pww@word@www.something.com")
```

when I see the above request in the VS browser it is like ..

```
http://username:pww
```

and the result is "Page Not Found "

**When there is no special character in the password the link goes fine without any issues ..Please Help *Thanks In Advance***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
webbrowser.navigate("http://username:pww%40word@www.something.com")
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip , but the username & passwords are dynamic , i.e., getting from the user, is there any function which converts special character to its respective value .. Thanks

Comment: @N.Sai Harish: you should use .NET functions to create path's and url's then you dont must by hand writing this string secure functions, .NET will do it.

Answer (score 0):

Please use HTTP POST instead of HTTP GET to send passwords to your website.  Special characters don't matter so much with POST, and it's somewhat more secure (user's neighbor can't see the password in the URL bar).

If you must use GET, [URL-encode](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_urlencode.asp) the password.  For example, you can replace "@" with "%40".  For C#, see [HttpUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode%28VS.71%29.aspx).  You'll probably need to encode username and password separately, and then build the URL.